# Authenticating with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I'm building an app on top of ReactiveCocoa and Octokit.objC (github library). As part of my effort I'm using Octokits ReactiveCocoa signals to access resources that require authentication. A previous question '[Retrying an asynchronous operation using ReactiveCocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242566/retrying-an-asynchronous-operation-using-reactivecocoa)' does a nice job covering the case where the user wants to 'retry an asynchronous operation' **once**. I'm trying to figure out how to handle the case where you might want to retry **several** times.

In my specific case if authentication fails I want to go ask the user for their credentials. I'll either ask the user for their credentials a few times (2 or 3) and then halt if they fail or I'll just keep asking them for their credentials until they succeed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks - AYAL

Answer (score 2):

There is an operator called `-retry:` which accepts a count parameter. If you apply this operator to a signal, and that signal returns an error, it will re-subscribe to the signal (up to the specified number of times) when the error is received. So what you need is a signal that, when subscribed to, prompts the user for credentials.

```
@weakify(self);
RACSignal *requestCredentials = [RACSignal defer:^{

    @strongify(self);

    // (Prompt the user for credentials.)

    if (successful)
    {
        self.cachedCredentials = credentials;
        return [self authenticate:credentials];
    }
    else
    {
        return [RACSignal error:[[MyError alloc] init]];
    }

}];

// We try to authenticate using the cached credentials (the
// `-authenticate:` method returns a signal that attempts
// authentication when it is subscribed to). If the initial
// attempt to authenticate fails, we try 3 times to get the
// user to enter the correct credentials.
return [[self authenticate:self.cachedCredentials]
    catchTo:[requestCredentials retry:3]];
```